# readAsDataURL is not a blob, yet the images show

Tags: javascript, file, blob

I have a file input which then preview the images after adding. The images show, but I get:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."`

What's causing this, surely they wouldn't show still?

```js
$('#image-upload-input').on('change', function() {
    var files = document.getElementById('image-upload-input').files;

    for (var key in files) {
        if (files[key]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('.image-upload-container').append('<img src="'+ e.target.result +'" style="width: 100px;">');
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(files[key]);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="image-upload-input" type="file" multiple>

<div class="image-upload-container"></div>
```

Comment: try to see what you are reading with filereader. Make `console.dir(files[key])` on each iteration of `for...in`

Comment: So that'll give you the file object

Comment: Did you try or its just assumption ?

Comment: I tried it before posting to be sure the for loop was returning the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the `for( in )` loop. As it iterates it chokes on the length property - which is not a Blob Object. This happens because the `for( in )` iterates over all (enumerable) object properties and not just "own properties". [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

You have two choices:

- Stick to the traditional (and always works) `for()` loop
- Use the `for( of )` loop

The `for( of )` loop will only iterate "own properties" while the traditional `for()` loop will always, always work when a length property is available.

```js
$('#image-upload-input').on('change', function() {
    var files = document.getElementById('image-upload-input').files;

    for(file of files) {
        if (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('.image-upload-container').append('<img src="'+ e.target.result +'" style="width: 100px;">');
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="image-upload-input" type="file" multiple>

<div class="image-upload-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good example of few issues together.

1. Exception you get - is because files isn't real array, so `for ... in` - iterates over "0", "1"... "item","length" keys.
2. You can't use async function inside loop without isolating the scope
3. My personal opinion: don't use jQuery if you can :-)

```js
$('#image-upload-input').on('change', function() {
    var files = document.getElementById('image-upload-input').files;

    for (var key=0; key < files.length; key++) {
        (function(){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var file = files[key];
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.style= "width:100px";
                img.src = reader.result;
                $('.image-upload-container').append($(img));
            }
            reader. readAsDataURL(file);
        })();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="image-upload-input" type="file" multiple>

<div class="image-upload-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have ditched the FileReader for `URL.createObjectURL` and just use a regular for loop

```
$('#image-upload-input').on('change', function() {
  var files = document.getElementById('image-upload-input').files;

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
    $('.image-upload-container').append('<img src='+ url +' style="width: 100px;">');
  }
});
```

and possible added this extra attribute to the input

```
accept="image/*"
```